# REST: URI and method to get resource statistics

Tags: rest, restful-url

What is the correct (best) way to get statistics of a resource. E.g. I have such a resource

```
/tournaments
```

Which returns a list of tournaments (let's say paginated):

```
{
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: ...,
            created: ...,
            ...
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: ...,
            created: ...,
            ...
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to show a year chart with columns showing how many tournaments were created in a month. So I need something like these:

```
[
    year: 2014,
    month: 1,
    tournaments: 10,
],
[
    year: 2014,
    month: 2,
    tournaments: 8,
],
[
    year: 2014,
    month: 3,
    tournaments: 42,
],
...
```

Where should be such content put? In `/tournamets` resource or somewhere else? Under `GET` request?
Maybe something like these:

```
/tournaments/stats?year=2014
```

How should it look like?
Or maybe I should add those statistics to every `/tournament` response, beside to `items` node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you `GET` a single tournament? If you use

```
GET /tournaments/1234
```

where `1234` is the ID of one tournament, I think is not a good idea to use

```
GET /tournaments/stats
```

to get the statistics. `/tournaments` is a collection resource and `stats` is not the ID of one tornament in this collection.

So I'd  use a different resource, for example

```
GET /tournamentsstats
```

which could then be filtered

```
/tournamentsstats?year=2014
```

Comment: Yes I take a particular tournament by `GET /tournaments/1234`

Comment: I was just thinking about this exact problem and thought maybe having /statistics/<collection> would be nicer, what do you think?

e.g. /statistics/tournements/?year=2014